# Largest Adjacent Numbers- Values Incrementing Incorrectly

Tags: python, increment

I am writing this program to find the 13 adjacent digits in this number that, when added together, have the largest sum. When I run it, however, the b value does not start at 12; it starts at some obscenely high number and I cannot figure out why. Any idea why my a and b values are not incrementing correctly?

```
num = "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352031277450632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511125069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

a = 0
b = 12
greatest = 0


while b != len(str(num)):
    num = str(num)
    newNum = num[a:b]
    total = 0
    for num in newNum:
        num = int(num)
        total += num
    if total > greatest:
        greatest = total
    a+=1
    b+=1
    print(b)

print(greatest)
```

Comment: how about not redefining `num` and using *other words* for *other variables* instead?

Comment: Don't reuse variable names in the same scope.

Comment: Also, `b` is starting at 12 just fine.

Comment: @ev. how else would i write it?

Comment: @user2357112 not when I run it. Maybe my pycharm interpreter is whack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you are reusing `num` in the inner loop, which renders the "original" `num` wrong after the first run.

Additionally, if you want a `13` digits run-in, you'd better start with `b = 13`

And furthermore, there is no need for `str(num)` since it is already a string, and no need to change `b` along the program. You can also replace the inner loop with a `sum` upon `map`.

Here is what it should look like after these changes:

```
num = "731671765313306249192251196744265747423553491949349698352031277450632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511125069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

index = 0
run_in = 13
greatest = 0

while index + run_in < len(num):
    num_slice = num[index: index + run_in]
    slice_sum = sum(map(int, num_slice))

    if slice_sum > greatest:
        greatest = slice_sum

    index += 1

print(greatest)
```

If you are into super functions, you can create the same effect with a list comprehension and a `max` closure, iterating all possible indexes (until the length of the number minus the run in):

```
greatest = max(sum(map(int, num[index: index + run_in])) for index in range(len(num) - run_in))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def largest(num, k):
    num = str(num)
    if len(num) < k: raise ValueError("Need a number with at least {} digits".format(k))
    currsum = sum(int(i) for i in num[:k])
    answer = currsum, 0
    i = k+1
    while i < len(num):
        currsum -= int(num[i-k])
        currsum += int(num[i])
        if currsum > answer[0]: answer = currsum, i
        i += 1
    return answer

total, ind = largest(myNum, 13)
print("The maximum sum of digits is {}, starting at index {}".format(total, ind))
```